# mDNS / Bonjour thourgh WLAN and VLAN

Tags: networking, router, subnet, vlan, bonjour

I have here the following situation:

```
Zyxel USG20 -> VLAN -> Server (192.168.50.xx) (local_1)
|
| -> Switch -> wired devices (192.168.80.xx) (local_2)
-> LEDE WLAN ROUTER -> Mobile Devices (192.168.80.xx) (local_2)
```

Im running a Homekit server in the VLAN Section with an IP in the 50.xx range. 
Now i would like to be able to discover the IP by mDNS / Bonjour from a mobile Device in the Range 80.xx

I have added rules in the USG20 for port 5353 to pass from local_2 to local_1 and added a rule for the IP 244.0.0.251 to pass from local_2 to local_1

But im not able to discover the server in the VLAN. 
What do i have to do to get this setup working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal – [mDNS uses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#page-6) a **link-local** multicast group (224.0.0.251 on IPv4, FF02::FB on IPv6), which is never forwarded by routers/gateways. Some implementations additionally enforce this by marking all mDNS packets with IP TTL=1. (That's all assuming your router has multicast forwarding enabled to begin with…)

To work across networks/subnets, mDNS needs to be proxied at application layer – for example, on a Linux or BSD router, you would run avahi-daemon with proxying enabled.

---

As you have a Raspberry Pi and a switch with 802.1Q VLANs, you can use the Rpi as a relay by connecting it to both 'client' and 'server' VLANs at once. (Note that you *shouldn't* create a dedicated VLAN just for the Rpi; that would completely defeat the point.)

In the comments you state that the Rpi is on port 4.

1. In the switch, mark port 4 (*not* LAG 4) as 'untagged' for one VLAN, and 'tagged' for all others. If the switch offers to configure the port's "PVID", make sure it matches the untagged VLAN.

   (Alternatively, it's okay to make all VLANs 'tagged'.)
2. In the Rpi, create virtual "vlan" interfaces for each *tagged* VLAN that it will be receiving. Assuming it runs Linux, you can do so temporarily using:

   ```
   ip link add eth0.100 link eth0 type vlan id 100
   ip link set eth0.100 up
   dhclient eth0.100
   ```

   (How to make this permanent depends on your distribution.)
3. In the Rpi, enable proxying (reflection) in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`:

   ```
   [reflector]
   enable-reflector=yes
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the best way would be to migrate these server services to an standalone raspberry which will be inside of the local_2 network i think. Or i use the raspberry as a link device. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that the mDNS proxy does not need to be run on a _router_ – just on a device that's directly attached to both networks (i.e. only needs the ability to receive multicasts).

Comment: So woul a raspberry fullfill the requirements? He will be attached to the local_2 network. The local_2 network is able to reach the local_1 network.

Comment: As you just recently found out, indirect reachability is not enough... the proxy must be directly on both subnets at the same time. For example, you _could_ put a Rpi on a 802.1Q "tagged"/trunk port with both your VLANs on it, if your gateway & switch support that.

Comment: I actually experimenting with that. I have created a VLAN on my RPI with ID 100. I have issued a dhcp command and i can see the request in the logs of the zywall. The zywall does answer with an offer of a correct IP (local_1 range) unfortunately, the rpi cannot receive this offer because the switch seems not to forward this answer to the pi because port is not configured correctly. Here is a picture of the actual config in the GS108 Switch: https://imgur.com/a/e2bntEy  im not an expert but i thought that the LAG will combine both traffic. My RPI Port is number 4. 7 and 8 are the servers

Comment: LAG means a different thing -- it doesn't combine VLANs' traffic, and "LAG 4" does not correspond to port 4. (What it does is combine two physical ports into one, e.g. 2x1Gbps into a single 2Gbps link; your switch supports up to 4 such groups.) Instead, you need to configure the VLANs directly on "Port 4". One of them should be untagged, all others tagged. Similar configuration needs to be done on the Rpi itself, by adding a virtual "vlan" interface.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working. The GS108 Menu is a little bit tricky. You have to select your VLAN ID from the dropdown to configure their members. Now the rpi has two ips. one from the local_1 net and one from the local_2 net. Now i have do config the avahi part